# GORM detached query by field of inherited class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have `Parent` classes and two `Child1` and `Child2` inherited from it:

```java
class Parent { }
class Child1 extends Parent {
    String prop1
}
class Child2 extends Parent {
    String prop2
}
```

And now I need to write select all Parent clases, but with criteria on `prop1` and `prop2`, i.e. something like this

```java
DetachedCriteria crit = Parent.where {
    (prop1 == 'Some value') || (prop2 == 'Some value')
}
crit.list()
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't query a class based on the properties of sub classes unless they are inherited. The parent has no concept of the properties of the sub classes in your example since they aren't inherited, making your query impossible. The best solution is going to be to query each of the sub classes individually and then merge the results.

Answer (score 1):

Using [sqlRestriction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) you can add arbitrary conditions to your query, so this might work

```
DetachedCriteria crit = Parent.where{
    sqlRestriction 'prop1 = ? OR prop2 = ?', ['value1', 'value2]
}
```

The only drawback is that SqlRestriction is not supported in unit tests.

Comment: Hey, now that's a great idea!